# Music playback stops when the phone sleeps

Tags: music, standby

I got a new Sony Xperia V (LT25i). When listening to music on the phone it stops playing music as soon as the phone goes into sleep. I have tried both Walkman player and <sup>3</sup> and both give the same problem.

Clarifications:

- I play from SD card and internal storage.
- It is a new phone, there is no app killers running that I know of.

Comment: do you have any task killer app running on ur phone? <br>

Comment: or any app like CPU tuner? If yes, apps like these have settings that force closes applications when put to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

If you're *streaming* music via your WiFi connection, you might wish to check your WiFi settings, and there go to "Advanced settings". Here is defined how WiFi should behave when the phone goes to "standby". The default usually is to disable WiFi, so you might want to set it to be kept alive:

[image: WiFi Advanced Settings] [image: WiFi sleep policy]
<sup>WiFi advanced settings and sleep policy</sup>

While screens might look a little different depending on the device being used, these screenshots should help you identifying the settings :)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an older thread, but have had the problem using WiFi to stream from Huawei phone to wireless speakers. Music stops when phone goes to sleep, but little you can do to phone except in developer mode turn stay awake on while charging. Finally solved problems by installing "Insomnia" a free simple app that switches between sleep on or off. Other stay awake apps just didn't work.... Happy days!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you provide a link to the app within your answer?

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem but was playing mp3s from my SD card. I used the vlc player instead and the problem was resolved :)